# How can I count number of iterations/steps to find answers of a method - RUBY

Tags: ruby, binary-search

How can I get the number of iterations/steps that this method takes to find an answer?

```
def binary_search(array, n)
 min = 0
 max = (array.length) - 1

 while min <= max
     middle = (min + max) / 2

    if array[middle] == n
          return middle
     elsif array[middle] > n
         max = middle - 1
     elsif array[middle] < n
       min = middle + 1
     end 
     end 
    "#{n} not found in this array"
 end
```

Comment: By using a counter inside the loop .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to use instead of a counter is the `.with_index` keyword. To use this you'll need to use `loop` instead of `while`, but it should work the same. Here's a basic example with output.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
loop.with_index do |_, index| # The underscore is to ignore the first variable as it's not used
  if (arr[index] % 2).zero?
    puts "even: #{arr[index]}"
  else
    puts "odd: #{arr[index]}"
  end

  break if index.eql?(arr.length - 1)
end

=>
odd: 1
even: 2
odd: 3
even: 4
odd: 5
even: 6
odd: 7
even: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count the number of iterations.

- Set a variable to 0 outside the loop
- Add 1 to it inside the loop
- When you return the index, return the count with it (`return [middle, count]`).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the code to count numbers of interations required by `binary_search` is to be used for testing or optimization. If so, the method `binary_search` should be modified in such a way that to produce production code it is only necessary to remove (or comment out) lines of code, as opposed to modifying statements. Here is one way that might be done.

```
def binary_search(array, n)
  # remove from production code lines marked ->              #******
  _bin_srch_iters = 0                                        #******
  begin                                                      #******
    min = 0
    max = (array.length) - 1
    loop do
      _bin_srch_iters += 1                                   #******
      middle = (min + max) / 2
      break middle if array[middle] == n
      break nil if min == max  
      if array[middle] > n
        max = middle - 1
      else # array[middle] < n
        min = middle + 1
      end 
    end
  ensure                                                     #****** 
    puts "binary_search reqd #{_bin_srch_iters} interations" #******  
  end                                                        #******
end
```

```
x = binary_search([1,3,6,7,9,11], 3)
#   binary_search reqd 3 interations
#=> 1
```

```
binary_search([1,3,6,7,9,11], 5) 
#   binary_search reqd 3 interations
#=> nil
```